# New Tag?: turtlebot4

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

As a new owner of a TurtleBot4 (lite) I am interested in quickly checking for "turtlebot4" posts.  turtlebot2 and turtlebot3 tags exist, but not turtlebot4.

At this point, I have only identified two other TurtleBot4 owners, but have high hopes I will not be alone for long.

I am 5 "rep points" short of being able to create the tag.

Someone with over 150 rep points want to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added turtlebot4 tag to your post which creates the tag.

In the future please ask meta questions on the paired meta forum: https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/

It's available in the top-right menus to switch to that site. I'm going to recommend this for closing with the hopes that a moderator can jump it over there.

(Note: This question has since been migrated from the main Robotics Stack Exchange site to the meta site.)